# Cloud Functions Static File Generator for Hosting Website

Tags: firebase

I want to see if it is possible to do the following with Firebase Cloud Functions.

Using a HTTP Trigger that runs a Cloud Function to load static template file(s) from Hosting (not Storage) into the Cloud Function. The Cloud Function would also load data from the Database. Once the two request were complete I would use a templating engine like Nunjucks to combine the data and template file into a HTML file. Finally the static HTMl file would be saved to the Hosting public directory

Basically I am looking to build and simple static file generator with everything Firebase has to offer.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but how did you solve it?

Comment: I never did. I now use Next.js for generating static website files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but depending on the amount of content not the greatest idea. Firebase Hosting is meant for versioned static assets and content can only be updated by deploying. If you try to do a deploy every time any data in your system changes, you'll quickly run into issues.

This is a kind of use case we're interested in for future work, but we don't have any functionality to support it at this time.

Comment: I see it as more of a manual thing and not deploying on every data change. I would create a single page application to act as the cms which would work with the database. Once the user is happy they would click a button that would trigger the Cloud Function to check for updated content and build out the static files.

Comment: The user to be able to publish changes via the web browser to add or overwrite static files rather then generating files locally and then having to do a full site deploy through the firebase command line.

Comment: It has been a while, any advances? Also I was thinking that after a deploy it would essentially invalidate any generated static files (references to outdated scripts for example)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use something like express to generate static html files using the fs node package, though personal I use a html generator locally to make the files and then deploy them to firebase